# Comparing Models, somebody can give me an exmple?

Tags: meshlab

**Comparing Models**, this is a feature of meshlab. there is a shot introdution in the web home of meshlab(http://www.meshlab.net/). 
  but how ?  there is none exmple.
  somebody can help me?  give a exmple or a document, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it has been mentioned in that short introduction, MeshLab compares two 3D models by calculating the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between them. This option is available under `Filters` menu (`Filters -> Sampling -> Hausdorff Distance`). Before applying this filter, you need to open two 3D models in MeshLab and select them from drop down menu in filter options. By default the filter output will be logged in the MeshLab console on right-bottom corner (If it is not visible press `Ctrl + L`).

---

You can also compare 3D models in MeshLab by calculating per vertex geometric distance between them (`Filters -> Sampling -> Distance from Reference Mesh`). The distance will be stored as per vertex quality. You can visualize these distances by enabling `Render -> Show Quality Contour` or `Render -> Show Quality Histogram`.

---

Here is a two part article on the same topic from MeshLab author Paolo Cignoni ([Part 1](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.in/2010/01/measuring-difference-between-two-meshes.html) and [Part 2](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.in/2010/03/measuring-distance-between-two-meshes-2.html)).

Comment: I get 'Cannot compute, it is the same mesh' error for both alternatives (Hausdorff distance and Distance from ref mesh), how can i solve this?

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak if the compared objects/meshes are the same, then Hausdorff distance equals 0, probably that's the reason if you are actually trying to compute the distance between two same meshes

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this topic is old and that my answer is for another product, but I was also looking into mesh comparison and I found that Cloud Compare
https://www.danielgm.net/cc/
does this job very well. It is also an open-source project and I found its UI quite friendly, in comparison to MeshLab.